# gstreamer not finding the cap I wanted

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to do a simple file dump with gstreamer from a decklink with gstreamer.

I've got a 2160p60 yuv420 video coming in on all 4 channels of my decklink 8k Pro.

gst-inspect-1.0 decklinkvideosrc includes this option:

```
  video/x-raw
              width: 3840
             height: 2160
    pixel-aspect-ratio: 1/1
     interlace-mode: progressive
          framerate: 60/1
             format: UYVY
        colorimetry: bt2020
        chroma-site: mpeg2
```

But when I do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v decklinkvideosrc device-number=1 ! 'video/x-raw, width=3840, height=2160, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, interlace-mode=progressive, framerate=60/1, format=UYVY,colorimetry=bt2020,chroma-site=mpeg2' ! filesink location=rp2
```

I get:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link decklinkvideosrc0 to filesink0, 
decklinkvideosrc0 can't handle caps video/x-raw, width=(int)3840, height=(int)2160, 
pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, framerate= 
(fraction)60/1, format=(string)UYVY, colorimetry=(string)bt2020, chroma-site= 
(string)mpeg2
```

If I request:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v decklinkvideosrc device-number=1

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecklinkVideoSrc:decklinkvideosrc0: hw-serial-number = 
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... 
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecklinkVideoSrc:decklinkvideosrc0.GstPad:src: caps = 
video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)486, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)10/11, 
interlace-mode=(string)interleaved, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, field-order= 
(string)bottom-field-first, format=(string)UYVY, colorimetry=(string)bt601, chroma- 
site=(string)mpeg2
```

If I select this (which isn't my source) I don't get an error but it stalls.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to launch it with `GST_DEBUG=3` (or 4, but it prints a lot of useless informations)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the Decklink element does not completely configure itself by downstream caps.

Instead I believe you need to set its properties to output the desired format via the `mode` property. And also eventually via the `video-mode` property.

So for your case maybe something like:

```
decklinkvideosrc device-number=1 mode=2160p60 video-mode=8bit-yuv ! filesink location=...
```

Comment: Thanks.
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0  decklinkvideosrc device-number=2 mode=2160p60 video-format=1 connection=1 ! 'video/x-raw, width=3840, height=2160, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, interlace-mode=progressive, framerate=60/1, format=UYVY,colorimetry=bt2020,chroma-site=mpeg2' ! filesink location=rp1
 

0:00:00.055237048 26185 0x55d50df3a2d0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<decklinkvideosrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
...
New clock: GstSystemClock
but still stuck.. thoughts?